# SQL Server - Grouping Combination of possibilities by fixed value

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, cube, rollup

[image]

I have to create cheapest basket which inculde fixed items.

For example for a basket which have **(5)** items

1 and 4 = (1 * 50) + (1 * 100) = 150

**2 and 3 = (1 * 60) + (1 * 80)  = 140** -- *this is my guy*

2 and 2 and 1 = (1 * 60) + (1 * 60) + (1 * 50) = 170

3 and 3 = (1 * 80) + (1 * 80)  = 160  **** this 6 items but total item can exceed min items. The important thing is total cost...
....

Also this is valid for any number of items a basket may have. Also there are lots of stores and each stores have different package may include several items.

How can handle this issue with SQL?

## UPDATE

Here is example data generation code. Recursive CTE solutions are more expensive. I should finish the job under 500-600ms over 600-700 stores each time. this is a package search engine. Manual scenario creation by using ´#temp´ tables or ´UNUION´ is 15-20 times cheaper then Recursive CTE.

Also concatenating `Item` or `PackageId` is very expensive. I can found required package id or item after selecting cheapest package with join to source table.

I am expecting a megical solution which can be ultra fast and get the correct option. 
Only cheapest basket required for each store. Manual scenario creation is very fast but sometimes fail for correct cheapest basket.

```
                CREATE TABLE #storePackages(
                StoreId int not null,
                PackageId int not null,
                ItemType int not null, -- there are tree item type 0 is normal item, 1 is item has discount 2 is free item
                ItemCount int not null,
                ItemPrice decimal(18,8) not null,
                MaxItemQouta int not null, -- in generaly a package can have between 1 and 6 qouata but in rare can up to 20-25
                MaxFullQouta int not null -- sometimes a package can have additional free or discount item qouta. MaxFullQouta will always greater then MaxItemQouta
            )

            declare @totalStores int
            set @totalStores = (SELECT TOP 1 n = number FROM master..[spt_values] WHERE number BETWEEN 200 AND 400 ORDER BY NEWID())

            declare @storeId int;
            declare @packageId  int;
            declare @maxPackageForStore int;
            declare @itemMinPrice decimal(18,8);
            set @storeId = 1;
            set @packageId = 1

            while(@storeId <= @totalStores)
                BEGIN
                    set @maxPackageForStore = (SELECT TOP 1 n = number FROM master..[spt_values] WHERE number BETWEEN 2 AND 6 ORDER BY NEWID())
                    set @itemMinPrice = (SELECT TOP 1 n = number FROM master..[spt_values] WHERE number BETWEEN 40 AND 100 ORDER BY NEWID())
                        BEGIN
                            INSERT INTO #storePackages
                            SELECT DISTINCT 
                             StoreId = @storeId
                            ,PackageId = CAST(@packageId + number AS int) 
                            ,ItemType = 0
                            ,ItemCount = number
                            ,ItemPrice = @itemMinPrice + (10 * (SELECT TOP 1 n = number FROM master..[spt_values] WHERE number BETWEEN pkgNo.number AND pkgNo.number + 2  ORDER BY NEWID()))
                            ,MaxItemQouta = @maxPackageForStore
                            ,MaxFullQouta =  @maxPackageForStore + (CASE WHEN number > 1 AND number < 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
                            FROM master..[spt_values] pkgNo
                            WHERE number BETWEEN 1 AND @maxPackageForStore
                            UNION ALL
                            SELECT DISTINCT 
                             StoreId = @storeId
                            ,PackageId = CAST(@packageId + number AS int) 
                            ,ItemType = 1
                            ,ItemCount = 1
                            ,ItemPrice = (@itemMinPrice / 2) + (10 * (SELECT TOP 1 n = number FROM master..[spt_values] WHERE number BETWEEN pkgNo.number AND pkgNo.number + 2  ORDER BY NEWID()))
                            ,MaxItemQouta = @maxPackageForStore
                            ,MaxFullQouta =  @maxPackageForStore  + (SELECT TOP 1 n = number FROM master..[spt_values] WHERE number BETWEEN 0 AND 2 ORDER BY NEWID())
                            FROM master..[spt_values] pkgNo
                            WHERE number BETWEEN 2 AND (CASE WHEN @maxPackageForStore > 4 THEN 4 ELSE @maxPackageForStore END)


                        set @packageId = @packageId + @maxPackageForStore;
                        END
                set @storeId =@storeId + 1;
                END

            SELECT * FROM #storePackages
            drop table #storePackages
```

## MY SOLUTION

First of all I am thankful for everyone who try to help me. However all suggested solutions are based on CTE. As I said before recursive CTEs cause performace problems when hunderds of stores are considered. Also multiple packages are requested for one time. This means, I request can include mutiple baskets. One is 5 items other is 3 items and another one is 7 items...

### Last Solution

First of all I generates all possible scenarios in a table by item size... By this way, I have option eleminate unwanted scenarios.

```
CREATE TABLE ItemScenarios(
   Item int,
   ScenarioId int,
   CalculatedItem int  --this will be joined with Store Item
)
```

Then I generated all possible scenario from 2 item to 25 item and insert to the `ItemScenarios` table. Scenarios can be genereated one time by using WHILE or recursive CTE. The advantage of this way, scenarios generated only for one time.

#### Resuls are like below.

```
Item          |   ScenarioId       |     CalculatedItem
--------------------------------------------------------
2                   1                     2
2                   2                     3
2                   3                     1
2                   3                     1
3                   4                     5
3                   5                     4
3                   6                     3
3                   7                     2
3                   7                     2
3                   8                     2
3                   8                     1
3                   9                     1
3                   9                     1
3                   9                     1
....
.....
......
25                  993                   10
```

By this way, I can restrict scenario sizes, Max different store, max different package etc.

Also I can eleminate some scenarios which matematically impossible cheapest then other. For example for 4 items request, some scenario

Scenario 1 : 2+2

Scenario 2: 2+1+1

Scenario 3: 1+1+1+1

Among these scenarios; It is impossible Scenario 2 would be cheapest basket. Because,

If **Scenario 2** < **Scenario 3** --> **Scenario 1** would be lower then **Scenario** 2. Because the thing decreasing cost is 2 item price and **Scenario 1* have double 2 items

Also If **Scenario 2** < **Scenario 1** --> **Scenario 3** would be lower then **Scenario** 2

Now, If I delete scenarios like **Scenario 2** I would gain some performance advantages.

Now I can chose chepest item prices among stores

```
DECLARE @requestedItems int;
SET @requestedItems = 5;

CREATE TABLE #JoinedPackageItemWithScenarios(
   StoreId int not null,
   PackageId int not null,
   ItemCount int not null,
   ItemPrice decimal(18,8) 
   ScenarioId int not null,
)
INSERT INTO #JoinedPackageItemWithScenarios
 SELECT
    SPM.StoreId  
   ,SPM.PackageId 
   ,SPM.ItemCount 
   ,SPM.ItemPrice 
   ,SPM.ScenarioId
   FROM (
      SELECT 
            SP.StoreId  
           ,SP.PackageId 
           ,SP.ItemCount 
           ,SP.ItemPrice 
           ,SC.ScenarioId
           ,RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SP.StoreId,SC.ScenarioId,SP.ItemCount ORDER BY SP.ItemPrice) 
      FROM ItemScenarios SC
      LEFT JOIN StorePackages AS SP ON SP.ItemCount = SC.CalculatedItem
      WHERE SC.Item = @requestedItems
 ) SPM
 WHERE SPM.RowNumber = 1

-- NOW I HAVE CHEAPEST PRICE FOR EACH ITEM, I CAN CREATE BASKET

 CREATE TABLE #selectedScenarios(
   StoreId int not null,
   ScenarioId int not null,
   TotalItem int not null,
   TotalCost decimal(18,8) 
)
 INSERT INTO #selectedScenarios
 SELECT 
      StoreId
     ,ScenarioId
     ,TotalItem 
     ,TotalCost 
  FROM (
     SELECT 
           StoreId
          ,ScenarioId
          --,PackageIds = dbo.GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(PackageId AS nvarchar(20))) -- CONCATENING PackageId decreasing performance here. We can joing seleceted scenarios with #JoinedPackageItemWithScenarios after selection complated.
          ,TotalItem = SUM(ItemCount)
          ,TotalCost = SUM(ItemPrice)
          ,RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY StoreId ORDER BY SUM(ItemPrice))
        FROM #JoinedPackageItemWithScenarios JPS
        GROUP BY StoreId,ScenarioId
        HAVING(SUM(ItemCount) >= @requestedItems)
     ) SLECTED
     WHERE RowNumber = 1

  -- NOW WE CAN POPULATE PackageIds if needed

  SELECT 
      SS.StoreId
     ,SS.ScenarioId
     ,TotalItem = MAX(SS.TotalItem)
     ,TotalCost = MAX(SS.TotalCost)
     ,PackageIds = dbo.GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(JPS.PackageId AS nvarchar(20)))
    FROM #selectedScenarios SS
    JOIN #JoinedPackageItemWithScenarios AS JPS ON JPS.StoreId = SS.StoreId AND JPS.ScenarioId = SS.ScenarioId
    GROUP BY SS.StoreId,SS.ScenarioId
```

#### SUM

In my test, this way is mimimum 10 times faster then recursive CTE, especially when number of stores and requested items increased. Also It gets 100% correct results. Because recursive CTE tried milions of unrequired JOINs when number of stores and requested items increased.

Comment: Huh?  You are measuring the number of items in a basket by either adding up the `PackageId` or the `Item` id?  This doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: ´PackageId´ is not important

Comment: @MehmetOtkun seems to me that PackageId is very important.  Because item appears to be the count of items in the package. so PackageId would be how to identify that package when querying it.

Comment: It's solvable by TSQL only when there is limited number of PakageIDs in the basket. Otherwise it should be solved my some algorithmic optimization methods like 'simplex method'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## MY SOLUTION

First of all I am thankful for everyone who try to help me. However all suggested solutions are based on CTE. As I said before recursive CTEs cause performace problems when hunderds of stores are considered. Also multiple packages are requested for one time. This means, A request can include mutiple baskets. One is 5 items other is 3 items and another one is 7 items...

### Last Solution

First of all I generates all possible scenarios in a table by item size... By this way, I have option eleminate unwanted scenarios.

```
CREATE TABLE ItemScenarios(
   Item int,
   ScenarioId int,
   CalculatedItem int  --this will be joined with Store Item
)
```

Then I generated all possible scenario from 2 item to 25 item and insert to the `ItemScenarios` table. Scenarios can be genereated one time by using WHILE or recursive CTE. The advantage of this way, scenarios generated only for one time.

#### Resuls are like below.

```
Item          |   ScenarioId       |     CalculatedItem
--------------------------------------------------------
2                   1                     2
2                   2                     3
2                   3                     1
2                   3                     1
3                   4                     5
3                   5                     4
3                   6                     3
3                   7                     2
3                   7                     2
3                   8                     2
3                   8                     1
3                   9                     1
3                   9                     1
3                   9                     1
....
.....
......
25                  993                   10
```

By this way, I can restrict scenario sizes, Max different store, max different package etc.

Also I can eleminate some scenarios which matematically impossible cheapest then other. For example for 4 items request, some scenario

Scenario 1 : 2+2

Scenario 2: 2+1+1

Scenario 3: 1+1+1+1

Among these scenarios; It is impossible Scenario 2 would be cheapest basket. Because,

If **Scenario 2** < **Scenario 3** --> **Scenario 1** would be lower then **Scenario** 2. Because the thing decreasing cost is 2 item price and **Scenario 1* have double 2 items

Also If **Scenario 2** < **Scenario 1** --> **Scenario 3** would be lower then **Scenario** 2

Now, If I delete scenarios like **Scenario 2** I would gain some performance advantages.

Now I can chose chepest item prices among stores

```
DECLARE @requestedItems int;
SET @requestedItems = 5;

CREATE TABLE #JoinedPackageItemWithScenarios(
   StoreId int not null,
   PackageId int not null,
   ItemCount int not null,
   ItemPrice decimal(18,8) 
   ScenarioId int not null,
)
INSERT INTO #JoinedPackageItemWithScenarios
 SELECT
    SPM.StoreId  
   ,SPM.PackageId 
   ,SPM.ItemCount 
   ,SPM.ItemPrice 
   ,SPM.ScenarioId
   FROM (
      SELECT 
            SP.StoreId  
           ,SP.PackageId 
           ,SP.ItemCount 
           ,SP.ItemPrice 
           ,SC.ScenarioId
           ,RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SP.StoreId,SC.ScenarioId,SP.ItemCount ORDER BY SP.ItemPrice) 
      FROM ItemScenarios SC
      LEFT JOIN StorePackages AS SP ON SP.ItemCount = SC.CalculatedItem
      WHERE SC.Item = @requestedItems
 ) SPM
 WHERE SPM.RowNumber = 1

-- NOW I HAVE CHEAPEST PRICE FOR EACH ITEM, I CAN CREATE BASKET

 CREATE TABLE #selectedScenarios(
   StoreId int not null,
   ScenarioId int not null,
   TotalItem int not null,
   TotalCost decimal(18,8) 
)
 INSERT INTO #selectedScenarios
 SELECT 
      StoreId
     ,ScenarioId
     ,TotalItem 
     ,TotalCost 
  FROM (
     SELECT 
           StoreId
          ,ScenarioId
          --,PackageIds = dbo.GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(PackageId AS nvarchar(20))) -- CONCATENING PackageId decreasing performance here. We can joing seleceted scenarios with #JoinedPackageItemWithScenarios after selection complated.
          ,TotalItem = SUM(ItemCount)
          ,TotalCost = SUM(ItemPrice)
          ,RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY StoreId ORDER BY SUM(ItemPrice))
        FROM #JoinedPackageItemWithScenarios JPS
        GROUP BY StoreId,ScenarioId
        HAVING(SUM(ItemCount) >= @requestedItems)
     ) SLECTED
     WHERE RowNumber = 1

  -- NOW WE CAN POPULATE PackageIds if needed

  SELECT 
      SS.StoreId
     ,SS.ScenarioId
     ,TotalItem = MAX(SS.TotalItem)
     ,TotalCost = MAX(SS.TotalCost)
     ,PackageIds = dbo.GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(JPS.PackageId AS nvarchar(20)))
    FROM #selectedScenarios SS
    JOIN #JoinedPackageItemWithScenarios AS JPS ON JPS.StoreId = SS.StoreId AND JPS.ScenarioId = SS.ScenarioId
    GROUP BY SS.StoreId,SS.ScenarioId
```

#### SUM

In my test, this way is mimimum 10 times faster then recursive CTE, especially when number of stores and requested items increased. Also It gets 100% correct results. Because recursive CTE tried milions of unrequired JOINs when number of stores and requested items increased.

Comment: hmmm, I am curious as to your actual code this is simply a description of steps but doesn't show the code to accomplish some of the key ones.  So someone else looking for a similar issue cannot replicate the solution.  Plus I am sure I and others whom answered are curious to learn your technique if it is that dramatically faster.  As it stands this is an incomplete answer.

Comment: If you are curious as how I generate pre-defined scenarios it is easy. By a simple recursive CTE or a WHILE clause scenarios can by generated. Other steps are complately coded in my solution. But my actual code is very complex. It has lots of different parametes. However I will add scenario generation code in a short time.

Comment: lol use a recursive cte...  My main curiosity was in how you where determining which scenarios to eliminate via code.  The main difference between our methods and yours is ours is are not limited to potential max N scenarios  where as yours is limited by the max number of scenarios you pre define as possible.  what if you have 50 items in 1 store that are all the cheapest at $1.  that would mean all 50 items would qualify as cheapest combination, and every combination of the 50 to the min items would qualify.  You have allowed a constraint in your answer not allowed by your question.

Comment: |o| I'm not opposed to recursive CTE. But in my case It works very slow. Also,%95 of requested items are between 2 and 7 in my project. For this reason constraints are useful for me. And I think everything has some constraints. Determinig chepest scenarios  depends on ´´´ROW_NUMBER´´´ by ordering price. Each store can have different price for the same item. Means it will have different PackageId. In first ordering, I found cheapest price for an item. In the second stage I grouping stores and scenarios and ordering by total price

Answer (score 1):

If you want combinations, you'll need a recursive CTE.  Preventing infinite recursion is a challenge.  Here is one method:

```
with cte as (
      select cast(packageid as nvarchar(4000)) as packs, item, cost
      from t
      union all
      select concat(cte.packs, ',', t.packageid), cte.item + t.item, cte.cost + t.cost
      from cte join
           t
           on cte.item + t.item < 10  -- some "reasonable" stop condition
     )
select top 1 cte.*
from cte
where cte.item >= 5
order by cost desc;
```

I'm not 100% sure that SQL Server will accept the join condition, but this should work.

Comment: 1. concat return nvarchar(4000), so you should cast packageId as the same type.
2. cte has column with name packs, but you used packageId in concat.
3. Your recursive cte didn't stop, because it will always try to join 1 and 1 item... you should add condition where packs <> concat(cte.packs,',', t.packageid)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to compare all possible permutations of items until the total items in the basket exceeds your total basket number, something like the following would do what you want.

```
DECLARE @N INT = 1;

DECLARE @myTable TABLE (storeID INT DEFAULT(1), packageID INT IDENTITY(1, 1), item INT, cost INT);
INSERT @myTable (item, cost) VALUES (1, 50), (2, 60), (3, 80), (4, 100), (5, 169), (5, 165), (4, 101), (2, 61);

WITH CTE1 AS (
    SELECT item, cost
    FROM (
        SELECT item, cost, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY cost) RN
        FROM @myTable) T
    WHERE RN = 1)
, CTE2 AS (
    SELECT CAST('items'+CAST(C1.item AS VARCHAR(10)) AS VARCHAR(4000)) items, C1.cost totalCost, C1.item totalItems
    FROM CTE1 C1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST(C2.items + ' + items' + CAST(C1.item AS VARCHAR(10)) AS VARCHAR(4000)), C1.cost + C2.totalCost, C1.item + C2.totalItems
    FROM CTE2 C2
    CROSS JOIN CTE1 C1
    WHERE C2.totalItems < @N)
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM CTE2
WHERE totalItems >= @N
ORDER BY totalCost, totalItems DESC;
```

Edited to deal with the issue @Matt mentioned.

Comment: this breaks down if you consider that the minimum number of items could be fully represented within 1 row e.g. (100,1) or (50,2) it ends up duplicating the items and the cost.

Comment: @Matt I assumed it would never be as simple as that, but really that's just a matter of not using a cross join in the first part of CTE2.

Comment: now (1,1) produced 1 and 1 for totalCost and totalItems.  I like where you are going with using the recursion and cross join together to create a more infinite combinations.  I am actually still trying to wrap my head around this direction rather than one I was going before but I think some of the problem would be the looking for total items < @N in one place and >= @N in the end.  because ultimately it shouldn't be limited in the cross join but I think your answer sparked something so I can get to a solution in what I was doing. cheers

Comment: @Matt The `< @N` in the recursive part of the CTE is because once you've reached `@N`, any more items you add are going to (necessarily) produce a larger cost. You only want to keep going through the recursive loop while you're less than the basket total. The `>= @N` at the end of it is so that you only get results that have reached at least `@N` items (which seems to be what the OP is requesting).

Comment: got where you are going with that but the cost is the constraint not the number of items it is possible that there are a high number of items but a lowest cost.  I am trying to work out an example in my mind I'll come back to it when I do cheers

Comment: @Matt My assumption is that the total items must be at least the basket number (5 in the example). The total cost must be the lowest of all possible combinations that reach the basket total. So if item1 had a cost of 1, then 5 of item1 would be the minimum. This should produce that answer, but maybe there's an error I'm not seeing.

Answer (score 0):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestResults') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #TestResults
    END

DECLARE @MinItemCount INT = 5

;WITH cteMaxCostToConsider AS (
    SELECT
       StoreId
       ,CASE
          WHEN (SUM(ItemCount) >= @MinItemCount) AND
          SUM(ItemPrice) < MIN(((@MinItemCount / ItemCount) + IIF((@MinItemCount % ItemCount) > 0, 1,0)) * ItemPrice) THEN SUM(ItemPrice)
          ELSE MIN(((@MinItemCount / ItemCount) + IIF((@MinItemCount % ItemCount) > 0, 1,0)) * ItemPrice)
       END AS MaxCostToConsider
    FROM
       storePackages
    GROUP BY
       StoreId
)

, cteRecursive AS (
    SELECT
      StoreId
      ,'<PackageId>' + CAST(PackageId AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + '</PackageId>' AS PackageIds
      ,ItemCount AS CombinedItemCount
      ,CAST(ItemPrice AS decimal(18,8)) AS CombinedCost
    FROM
       storePackages

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
      r.StoreId
      ,r.PackageIds + '<PackageId>' + CAST(t.PackageId AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + '</PackageId>'
      ,r.CombinedItemCount + t.ItemCount
      ,CAST(r.CombinedCost + t.ItemPrice AS decimal(18,8))
    FROM
       cteRecursive r
       INNER JOIN storePackages t
       ON r.StoreId = t.StoreId
       INNER JOIN cteMaxCostToConsider m
       ON r.StoreId = m.StoreId
      AND r.CombinedCost + t.ItemPrice <= m.MaxCostToConsider
)

, cteCombinedCostRowNum AS (
    SELECT
       StoreId
       ,CAST(PackageIds AS XML) AS PackageIds
       ,CombinedCost
       ,CombinedItemCount
       ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY StoreId ORDER BY CombinedCost) AS CombinedCostRowNum
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY StoreId ORDER BY CombinedCost) AS PseudoCartId
    FROM
       cteRecursive
    WHERE
       CombinedItemCount >= @MinItemCount
)

SELECT DISTINCT
    c.StoreId
    ,x.PackageIds
    ,c.CombinedItemCount
    ,c.CombinedCost
INTO #TestResults
FROM
    cteCombinedCostRowNum  c
    CROSS APPLY (
       SELECT( STUFF ( (
          SELECT ',' + PackageId
          FROM
             (SELECT T.N.value('.','VARCHAR(100)') as PackageId FROM c.PackageIds.nodes('PackageId') as T(N)) p
          ORDER BY
             PackageId
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
    ) as PackageIds
    ) x
WHERE
    CombinedCostRowNum = 1


SELECT *
FROM
    #TestResults
```

**Takes about 1000-2000 MS varies widely depending on combinations that have to be considered within test data (e.g. some times more or less data is generate by your script).**

this answer no doubt looks a bit more complicated than Gordon's or ZLKs but it handles Ties, repeated values, 1 package meeting the criteria and a few other things.  The main difference however is really in the last query where I take the XML that was build during the recursive query split it and then re-combined in order so that you can use DISTINCT and get a unique pairing e.g. package 2 + package 3 = 140 & package 3 + package 2 = 140 would be the first 2 results in all of the queries so using the XML to split then recombine allows that to be a single row.  But lets say you also had another row such as (1,5,2,60) that had 2 items and a cost of 60 this query will return that combination too.

You can cherry pick between the answers and use their method to get to the combinations and my methods to get to the final results etc.... But to explain the process of my query.

`cteMaxCostToConsider` - this is just a way of getting a cost to contain the recursive query to so that less records have to be considered. what it does is determines the cost of all of the packages together or the cost if you bought all of the same package to satisfy the minimum count.

`cteRecursive` - this is similar to ZLKs answer and a litte like Gordon's but what it does is goes out and continues to add items & item combinations until it reaches MaxCostToConsider.  If I limit to look at item count it could miss a situation where 7 items would be cheaper than 5 so by constraining to the determined Combined Cost it limits the recursion and performs better.

`cteCombinedCostRowNum` - This simply finds the lowest Combined Cost and at least the minimum item count.

The final query is a bit trickier but the cross apply splits the XML string build in the recursive cte to different rows re-orders those rows and then concatenates them again so that the reverse combination e.g. Package 2 & Package 3 reverse Package 3 & Package 2 becomes the same record and then calls distinct.

This is a bit more flexible than SELECT top N.  To see the difference add the following test cases to your test data 1 at a time:
(StoreId, PackageId, Item, Cost)

- (1,5,2,60)
- (1,6,1,1),(1,7,1,1)
- (1,8,50,1)

**Edited.**  The above will give you every combination of a store that will have the lowest combined cost.  The bug that you noted was due to `cteMaxCostToConsider`.  I was using `SUM(ItemPrice)` but sometimes `SUM(ItemCount)` related to it didn't have enough items in it to allow it to be considered for the MaxCostToConsider. I modified the case statement to correct that issue.

I have also modified to work with your data example your provided.  NOTE you should change your PackageId in that to an IDENTITY column though because I was getting the duplicate PackageIds within a store with the method you used.

Here is a modified version of your script to see what I am talking about:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('storePackages') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE storePackages
    END

CREATE TABLE storePackages(
    StoreId int not null,
    PackageId int not null IDENTITY(1,1),
    ItemType int not null, -- there are tree item type 0 is normal item, 1 is item has discount 2 is free item
    ItemCount int not null,
    ItemPrice decimal(18,8) not null,
    MaxItemQouta int not null, -- in generaly a package can have between 1 and 6 qouata but in rare can up to 20-25
    MaxFullQouta int not null -- sometimes a package can have additional free or discount item qouta. MaxFullQouta will always greater then MaxItemQouta
)

declare @totalStores int
set @totalStores = (SELECT TOP 1 n = number FROM master..[spt_values] WHERE number BETWEEN 200 AND 400 ORDER BY NEWID())

declare @storeId int;
declare @packageId  int;
declare @maxPackageForStore int;
declare @itemMinPrice decimal(18,8);
set @storeId = 1;
set @packageId = 1

while(@storeId <= @totalStores)
    BEGIN
        set @maxPackageForStore = (SELECT TOP 1 n = number FROM master..[spt_values] WHERE number BETWEEN 2 AND 6 ORDER BY NEWID())
        set @itemMinPrice = (SELECT TOP 1 n = number FROM master..[spt_values] WHERE number BETWEEN 40 AND 100 ORDER BY NEWID())
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO storePackages (StoreId, ItemType, ItemCount, ItemPrice, MaxFullQouta, MaxItemQouta)
                SELECT DISTINCT 
                    StoreId = @storeId
                --,PackageId = CAST(@packageId + number AS int) 
                ,ItemType = 0
                ,ItemCount = number
                ,ItemPrice = @itemMinPrice + (10 * (SELECT TOP 1 n = number FROM master..[spt_values] WHERE number BETWEEN pkgNo.number AND pkgNo.number + 2  ORDER BY NEWID()))
                ,MaxItemQouta = @maxPackageForStore
                ,MaxFullQouta =  @maxPackageForStore + (CASE WHEN number > 1 AND number < 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
                FROM master..[spt_values] pkgNo
                WHERE number BETWEEN 1 AND @maxPackageForStore
                UNION ALL
                SELECT DISTINCT 
                    StoreId = @storeId
                --,PackageId = CAST(@packageId + number AS int) 
                ,ItemType = 1
                ,ItemCount = 1
                ,ItemPrice = (@itemMinPrice / 2) + (10 * (SELECT TOP 1 n = number FROM master..[spt_values] WHERE number BETWEEN pkgNo.number AND pkgNo.number + 2  ORDER BY NEWID()))
                ,MaxItemQouta = @maxPackageForStore
                ,MaxFullQouta =  @maxPackageForStore  + (SELECT TOP 1 n = number FROM master..[spt_values] WHERE number BETWEEN 0 AND 2 ORDER BY NEWID())
                FROM master..[spt_values] pkgNo
                WHERE number BETWEEN 2 AND (CASE WHEN @maxPackageForStore > 4 THEN 4 ELSE @maxPackageForStore END)


            --set @packageId = @packageId + @maxPackageForStore;
            END
    set @storeId =@storeId + 1;
    END

SELECT * FROM storePackages
--drop table #storePackages
```

**No PackageIds Simply StoreId and Lowest CombinedCost - ~200-300MS depending on data**
Next if you don't care what Packages are in there and you only want 1 row per store you can do the following:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestResults') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #TestResults
    END

DECLARE @MinItemCount INT = 5

;WITH cteMaxCostToConsider AS (
    SELECT
       StoreId
       ,CASE
          WHEN (SUM(ItemCount) >= @MinItemCount) AND
          SUM(ItemPrice) < MIN(((@MinItemCount / ItemCount) + IIF((@MinItemCount % ItemCount) > 0, 1,0)) * ItemPrice) THEN SUM(ItemPrice)
          ELSE MIN(((@MinItemCount / ItemCount) + IIF((@MinItemCount % ItemCount) > 0, 1,0)) * ItemPrice)
       END AS MaxCostToConsider
    FROM
       storePackages
    GROUP BY
       StoreId
)

, cteRecursive AS (
    SELECT
      StoreId
      ,ItemCount AS CombinedItemCount
      ,CAST(ItemPrice AS decimal(18,8)) AS CombinedCost
    FROM
       storePackages

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
      r.StoreId
      ,r.CombinedItemCount + t.ItemCount
      ,CAST(r.CombinedCost + t.ItemPrice AS decimal(18,8))
    FROM
       cteRecursive r
       INNER JOIN storePackages t
       ON r.StoreId = t.StoreId
       INNER JOIN cteMaxCostToConsider m
       ON r.StoreId = m.StoreId
      AND r.CombinedCost + t.ItemPrice <= m.MaxCostToConsider
)

SELECT
    StoreId
    ,MIN(CombinedCost) as CombinedCost
    INTO #TestResults
FROM
    cteRecursive
WHERE
    CombinedItemCount >= @MinItemCount
GROUP BY
    StoreId

SELECT *
FROM
    #TestResults
```

**WITH PackageIds Only 1 Record Per StoreId - Varries widely depending on test data/combinations to consider ~600-1300MS**
Or if you still want package ids but you don't care which combination you choose and you only want 1 record then you can do:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestResults') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #TestResults
    END

DECLARE @MinItemCount INT = 5

;WITH cteMaxCostToConsider AS (
    SELECT
       StoreId
       ,CASE
          WHEN (SUM(ItemCount) >= @MinItemCount) AND
          SUM(ItemPrice) < MIN(((@MinItemCount / ItemCount) + IIF((@MinItemCount % ItemCount) > 0, 1,0)) * ItemPrice) THEN SUM(ItemPrice)
          ELSE MIN(((@MinItemCount / ItemCount) + IIF((@MinItemCount % ItemCount) > 0, 1,0)) * ItemPrice)
       END AS MaxCostToConsider
    FROM
       storePackages
    GROUP BY
       StoreId
)

, cteRecursive AS (
    SELECT
      StoreId
      ,CAST(PackageId AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS PackageIds
      ,ItemCount AS CombinedItemCount
      ,CAST(ItemPrice AS decimal(18,8)) AS CombinedCost
    FROM
       storePackages

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
      r.StoreId
      ,r.PackageIds + ',' + CAST(t.PackageId AS VARCHAR(MAX))
      ,r.CombinedItemCount + t.ItemCount
      ,CAST(r.CombinedCost + t.ItemPrice AS decimal(18,8))
    FROM
       cteRecursive r
       INNER JOIN storePackages t
       ON r.StoreId = t.StoreId
       INNER JOIN cteMaxCostToConsider m
       ON r.StoreId = m.StoreId
      AND r.CombinedCost + t.ItemPrice <= m.MaxCostToConsider
)

, cteCombinedCostRowNum AS (
    SELECT
       StoreId
       ,PackageIds
       ,CombinedCost
       ,CombinedItemCount
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY StoreId ORDER BY CombinedCost) AS RowNumber
    FROM
       cteRecursive
    WHERE
       CombinedItemCount >= @MinItemCount
)

SELECT DISTINCT
    c.StoreId
    ,c.PackageIds
    ,c.CombinedItemCount
    ,c.CombinedCost
INTO #TestResults
FROM
    cteCombinedCostRowNum  c
WHERE
    RowNumber = 1


SELECT *
FROM
    #TestResults
```

Note all bench marking is done on a 4 year old laptop Intel i7-3520M CPU 2.9 GHz with 8 GB of RAM and SAMSUNG 500 GB EVO SSD.  So if you run this on an appropriately resourced server I would expect exponentially faster.  There is also no doubt that adding indexes on storePackages would expedite the answer as well.

Comment: This solution is faster then others but not enough. Also it has some bugs. Some stores are not listed and some stores dublicated.

Comment: @MehmetOtkun I found the bug you referenced and the stores not listing where due to that.  Duplicate stores where because 2 things 1 more than 1 row may have the same lowest cost per store and 2 your packageids in your generated data where being re-used/duplicated when they should not have been.  As far as your 600-700 MS 2 of the answers above are within that range on an old laptop I use.  Just depends on how much data you want to see in fact if all you want is the storeid and lowest cost 200-300 MS.

Comment: @MehmetOtkun if my answer or another answer got you the result you needed please consider accepting it so that the question shows as having been answered and reputation points are awarded.  Plus I am curious as you never provided feedback when I gave you some benchmarded ms....

Comment: Thank you very much for everything. But recursive CTE cause huge performance probles for lots of cases. I write my own solution above.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly we'll should to find all combinations, and next select one with minimal price for seeking value

```
DECLARE @Table as TABLE (StoreId INT, PackageId INT, Item INT, Cost INT)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (1,1,1,50),(1,2,2,60),(1,3,3,80),(1,4,4,100)

DECLARE @MinItemCount INT = 5;

WITH cteCombinationTable AS (
    SELECT  cast(PackageId as NVARCHAR(4000)) as Package, Item, Cost
    FROM @Table
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CONCAT(o.Package,',',c.PackageId), c.Item + o.Item, c.Cost + o.Cost FROM @Table as c join cteCombinationTable as o on CONCAT(o.Package,',',c.PackageId) <> Package
    where o.Item < @MinItemCount
)

select top 1 * 
from cteCombinationTable
where item >= @MinItemCount
order by cast(cost as decimal)/@MinItemCount
```